# Unix "tail" that clears screen on truncation?

Tags: unix, tail

Using `tail -F` to follow a file that might not exist yet, and it works across truncations, as follows:

```
tail: cannot open `mylog.log' for reading: No such file or directory
tail: `mylog.log' has appeared;  following end of new file
run1
run1
run1
tail: mylog.log: file truncated
run2
run2
run2
```

I only want to see the current run's output, as multiple runs fit in a screen and it's hard to tell where one stops and the next begins.  Before executing a run, I find myself using

```
rm mylog.log; clear && tail -F mylog.log
```

But I have to remember to do that before every run.  I realize that if `tail` would clear the screen when truncation occurs, it would give me exactly the behavior that I want without requiring any interaction from me.

The `tail` man page didn't seem to indicate this was possible.  I'm sure I can't be the first to desire this behavior, has anyone else used other means to accomplish it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This snippet will work:

```
tail -F $LOGFILE 2>&1 | sed -e "$(echo -e "s/^\(tail: .\+: file truncated\)$/\1\e[2J/")"
```

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't thought of piping the output of a long-running program through sed.  Looks like that works, thanks!